# How to run wine inside a chrooted environment in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wine, chroot

I'm trying to run wine inside a 'pseudo' jail inside Ubuntu.

I've been able to debootstrap an Ubuntu install and run wine inside it so far.

Problem is that there are a LOT of libraries that are being included.

Is there a simple way to figure out which libraries are required by wine ?

I've tried ldd /usr/bin/wine

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7702000)
libwine.so.1 => /usr/bin/../lib32/libwine.so.1 (0xf75bf000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7590000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7433000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf742f000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7703000)
```

But that doesn't help me much to figure out which libraries are actually needed.

EDIT:
i'm running wine from Xvnc (.vnc/xstartup):

```
env DISPLAY=127.0.0.1$DISPLAY CHROOT_DIR=/home/chroot \
COMMAND="/usr/bin/wine $HOME/myapp.exe"
```

Where '/home/chroot' is the debootstrapped install.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There is, and it's called `schroot`. It helps you set up and maintain chroot environments.

Another option would be to manually run `debootstrap` on your prospective chroot, so you have apt and dpkg available inside it (so you can just run `apt-get install wine` while you're in the chroot).

More information on both options is available on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot)

Comment: Nice; i'll give a try. But do you know a way to find out wine1.3 dependencies without having to debootstrap anything ?

Comment: The idea is to get just the veeery bare minimal system to run wine and wine only.

Comment: apt-cache show wine1.3; yes but it's not really human friendly.

Comment: Use `debootstrap --variant=minbase` -- that will make a chroot with only the minimal ("essential") set of packages and apt.

Comment: ok, minbase still got a bunch of stuff that i don't need, like e2fs, adduser etc ... i'm trying " debootstrap --variant=fakechroot --arch i386 natty" but it says " This variant requires fakechroot environment to be started" can you explain this ?